# Will a c# program the uses Microsoft.Web.Administration version 7.0 work with newer versions of iis

Tags: c#-4.0, iis

I am building a c# program that configures a web site (including application pool and authentication settings) using the nuget package Microsoft.Web.Administration 7.0.0.0.

This works on my development machine and also on my virtual server where iis 7.0 is installed.

But I wonder if it will still work on production servers that have newer version of iis (iis7.5 and above) installed.

Comment: What are you running as your development machine? Windows Vista or 7?

Comment: I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Not very likely, as MWA is machine dependent. The NuGet package is just a nightmare you should avoid, https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/05/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know/